# Is it possible to have a docker container with multiple lambda functions on it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

## Scenario

I have several lambda functions that will all work under the same enviroment (`node v14.x`). These functions will be independently (maybe in the future they will need to communicate with each other)

## Problem

I have seen that we can use [public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:14.2021.12.23.17](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs) image to use Node's image. But in this example we are talking about a single lambda function.

My project is as follow:

```
lambda-functions
  - lambda function A
  - lambda function B
  - lambda function C
```

What I'm looking for is a scenario where I can dockerize all of these lambda functions under the same project.

I have been looking into `docker-compose` and I was thinking of having my solution as follow:

```
lambda-functions
  - lambda function A
    - Dockerfile
  - lambda function B
    - Dockerfile
  - lambda function C
    - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

## Question

Is this a good approach to this problem? Are there other options that I can follow, if yes which ones? With this approach, is it possible to deploy the image of each lambda function to AWS? Would it be possible to do some integration testing here?

I understand that this question seems a bit open ended question but what I'm looking for are options and understand if my solution is feasible. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable to me. Best practice is to have one process per container, and you're following that.

Comment: Any update on an approach that worked? I'm in this same situation and it seems like creating so many duplicate docker images would be a waste of resources.

Comment: @JasonGreen what I ended up doing is exactly what is in the question. Doing a `docker-compose` and dockerizing each project inside its own container as a service. I ended up using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) in each container to help deploy it to lambda (and other services such as watch log)

Comment: I think you could do with one image, but configure lambda container entrypoint/cmd to trigger the lambda you want. So the config for one lambda could have cmd `app.handlerA`, the other `app.handlerB` etc.